# Show that a set is measurable with respect to Borel product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ denote the real line with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $X=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})\times(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ have the product $\sigma$-algebra. Show that
>
> > A = { $(x,y)\in X:|x-y|<1$ }
>
> is a measurable set.

I know that

> $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ = <{$U\times V: U,V \in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$}> = <{$U\times V: U,V \subset \mathbb{R}$ open}>

So I think I have to write A as a product of two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $\mathcal B(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$ is **generated** by the products of open sets. Therefore a $\mathcal B(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$-measurable set need not be the product of two open sets, as indeed your set $A$ is not.

Comment: You might try to show that, in general, an open set is measurable in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Show that any open set in the plane is the union of rectangles with the sides parallel to the axes and corners at points with rational coordinates.

Comment: @AndreasT I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. So I could show that any open set X $\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and that A is an open set, to prove it?

Comment: Indeed, that is what he must have meant. $A$ is indeed open. But you could also follow my suggestion above, substituting $A$ for “any open set”.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x, y) = |x - y|$ is continuous, so the preimage of $(-\infty, 1)$ is open, hence Borel.